# Cypress deep equal works weirdly

Tags: cypress, cypress-each

I started learning cypress today and trying to write the test below

```
it('Validate Price High - Low sorting', () => {
    let unsortedItemPrices = [];
    const sortedItemPrices = [];

    unsortedItemPrices.sort((a, b) => parseFloat(a) - parseFloat(b)).reverse();
    cy.get(inventoryPage.itemsPrice).each((item) => {
      unsortedItemPrices.push(item.text().replace('$', ''));
    });

    cy.get(inventoryPage.sortDropdown).get('option').should('have.length', 4);
    cy.get(inventoryPage.sortDropdown).select('hilo');
    cy.get(inventoryPage.itemsPrice).each(($item) => {
      sortedItemPrices.push($item.text().replace('$', ''));
    });
    

    cy.task('log', unsortedItemPrices.sort((a, b) => parseFloat(a) - parseFloat(b)).reverse());
    cy.task('log', sortedItemPrices);
    expect(sortedItemPrices).to.deep.equal(unsortedItemPrices.sort().reverse());
  });
```

The 2 log statements returns these lines, which is weird as when I try separately I see the data sorted properly. However the expect().to.deep.equal() statement above doesn't return an error.

```
[ '29.99', '9.99', '15.99', '49.99', '7.99', '15.99' ]
[ '49.99', '29.99', '15.99', '15.99', '9.99', '7.99' ]
```

What is more weird that if I edit the log with like this

```
cy.task('log', unsortedItemPrices.sort((a, b) => parseFloat(a) - parseFloat(b)).reverse().push(1));
```

then I do get an error, but it says

```
AssertionError: expected [] to deeply equal [ 1 ]
      + expected - actual

      -[]
      +[ 1 ]
```

Can someone please explain what is going on? This is totally confusing for me :|

Comment: One thing thats compounding your confusion is both `sort` and `reverse` modify the array in place and return a reference to the same array, as opposed to return a new array with the modifications. That means when you are logging with these calls, the array is actually getting reversed an additional time. First change all of them to [toSorted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toSorted) and [toReversed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toReversed). This will help you at least debug easier.

Comment: Additionally to this that final call `expect(sortedItemPrices).to.deep.equal(unsortedItemPrices.sort().reverse());` is calling `sort` without a callback so its trying to sort the object references themselves rather than the property inside the object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your test, you have some `cy.get()` commands to get the values off the page, but you go ahead and run the `expect().to.deep.eq()` ***before*** these command have completed.

That's because `cy.get()` commands are asynchronous, and need to be waited on before using the values extracted from the page.

So your expect is comparing the empty arrays, equivalent to

```js
expect([]).to.deep.equal([])
```

which explains this message after you `push(1)`

> AssertionError: expected `[]` to deeply equal `[ 1 ]`

---

**How to fix**

Just wrap your comparison in a `cy.then()` to ensure it is performed after the values are extracted.

Also note `.sort()` and `.reverse()` are **in-place** methods that affect the original array, so you don't want to call then twice (which you have correctly avoided doing, but it's easy to overlook that issue).

```js
const sortFn = (a, b) => parseFloat(a) - parseFloat(b)

let unsortedItemPrices = [];
const sortedItemPrices = [];

cy.get(inventoryPage.itemsPrice).each($item => {
  unsortedItemPrices.push($item.text().replace('$', ''))
})

cy.get(inventoryPage.sortDropdown).get('option').should('have.length', 4);
cy.get(inventoryPage.sortDropdown).select('hilo');
cy.get(inventoryPage.itemsPrice).each($item => {
  sortedItemPrices.push($item.text().replace('$', ''))
})

cy.then(() => {
  // sort() and reverse() work in-place, so we can apply first
  unsortedItemPrices.sort(sortFn).reverse()
  // then compare
  expect(sortedItemPrices).to.deep.equal(unsortedItemPrices)
})
```

---

**A clearer test**

IMO a cleaner way to structure the test is to map elements to values instead of using `.each()`

```js
const sortFn = (a, b) => parseFloat(a) - parseFloat(b)
const mapFn = ($items) => [...$items].map(item => item.innerText.replace('$', '')

cy.get(inventoryPage.itemsPrice)
  .then(mapFn)
  .then(unsortedItemPrices => {

    // create a new array for expected values
    const expectedSortedItemPrices = [...unsortedItemPrices.sort(sortFn).reverse()]

    cy.get(inventoryPage.sortDropdown).get('option')
      .should('have.length', 4);
    cy.get(inventoryPage.sortDropdown).select('hilo');
    cy.get(inventoryPage.itemsPrice)
      .then(mapFn)
      .should(sortedItemPrices => {

        // using should() instead of then() gives some retry
        // in case the page sorting happens asynchronously
        // (not likely but you don't know the internal implementation)

        expect(sortedItemPrices).to.deep.equal(expectedSortedItemPrices)
      })
  })
```

Comment: Thanks TesterDick.. I did not know cypress runs stuff async :)